# Getting cycles per byte for my algorithm?

Tags: c++, c, cpu, cpu-speed

I know the theory but have problem with practical implementation. I wrote an AES algorithm in C. Now, I would like to know, how many cycles per byte it "has". I know that I have to (is that 100% rigth?):

1. Calculate speed of an algorithm in bytes per second
2. Get clock speed in hertz
3. Divide speed of an algorithm in bytes per second by clock speed in hertz
4. Take the reciprocal from 3.
5. Measure speed of an algorithm in gigabytes per second
6. Divide speed of an algorithm in gigabytes per second by the clock speed in gigahertz
7. Take the reciprocal from 6.

Is it possible to do it in C/C++? How to make it and what should I use/look for to make it?

Im interested in Linux/Windows/Mac solutions.

Comment: This will be a platform-dependent thing. On x86 there's `rdtsc` instruction that directly accesses the cycles counter of the processor. Using that simplifies things greatly. You can call it from C code using inline assembly - Google will help find snippets of doing that.

Comment: @sharptooth: so it is more platform-dependant, than os-dependent? And how about x86_64 architecture?

Comment: I'd guess you can use `rdtsc` on x86-64 no problem. I'd be very surprised to find it's not available there. If you can use `rdtsc` - you don't care of the OS anymore.

Comment: what are 7. and 4. for?

Comment: Note that using RDTSC has two gotchas: First, it includes cycles spent while your process is not running (so running it with realtime priority may be a good idea), and also you must flush the instruction pipeline (e.g. CPUID) before calling it, if you want precise results. Or, you could do a very large number of measurements and take the smallest overall result (less reliable but probably "good enough"). Also, you will obviously want to run many iterations on the same block to avoid being bound by cache/memory bandwidth. And in that case, you must subtract the overhead of the loop.

Comment: @sharptooth: Intel changed the specification of `rdtsc` several years ago so that, on new processors, it returns real time, not a cycle count. E.g., if the CPU frequency speeds up or slows down (as it does for heat or efficiency reasons), `rdtsc` tracks real time, not the number of cycles executed.

Comment: @phresnel: 3 and 6 have reciprocals of 1/3 and 1/6. If you take the reciprocals from 3 and 6, then they do not have reciprocals anymore. Then the real numbers are no longer a field.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Lol, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just algebra, not an equation or a theory.

If you already know bytes/second, and clock speed (cycles/second), then

```
(bytes/second) / (cycles/second) => bytes/cycle
1 / (bytes/cycle) => cycles/byte
```

---

If you don't know *bytes per second*, you can calculate it by:

1. get a high-resolution timestamp *T<sub>1</sub>* suitable for this kind of measurement
2. run your algorithm *N* times over *B* bytes
3. get another timestamp *T<sub>2</sub>*
4. subtract the timestamps one from the other, to give the elapsed time *E = T<sub>2</sub> - T<sub>1</sub>*
5. you have now processed *(N* **B)* bytes in *E* time units
6. repeat several times
7. if your measurements are unstable, or your duration *E* uncomfortably close to zero, or suspiciously close to some system timer granularity, increase *N* and/or *B* and try again. Actually, do this a few times anyway to confirm you get a linear relationship between bytes processed and time taken
8. scale your time units (nanoseconds, microseconds, whatever they are) into seconds, if that's how you want to display the result

Note that if your "timestamp" above is actually a cycle counter, you can skip the cycles/second stage. Otherwise, you can just read off the CPU frequency from the system/hardware information tool for your platform.

For POSIX, a sensible timer might be `clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID,...)`, for example. You should be able to find example code for `rdtsc`, documentation for the best Windows timing function etc. by searching.

---

As for actually taking the measurements, there are good suggestions in the comments. You need to:

- take a large (enough) number of samples for it to be reliable
- ideally with nothing else contending for resources, if not with FIFO/realtime scheduling
- either making sure any CPU clock scaling is turned off, or discard the first samples where it was warming up

Comment: Ok, any ideas HOW to get bytes/second and cycles/second in C/C++ code?

Comment: Is it _really_ the subtraction and division you're confused by, or are you just trying to ask how to get a suitable timestamp?

Comment: I think both. Im a litte bit confused with this, so if you would be so kind to explain to me how to get a get a suitable I will be very thankful:) Of course I will read about `rdtsc`, thanks

Comment: Why do my cycles/byte reduce considerably with increasing message length?

Comment: Possibly because you have some fixed overhead which is a larger proportion of smaller messages, or because of some clock scaling/turbo or cache warming effect? Ask your own question with some detail of your code and results if you want a real answer